# Pointing a variable to a member function from a different class type

Tags: c++, class, pointers

In C++, how do i  call a method  member of class A from a class  B,  using a pointer? By the way Class A and B are of different types.

I read that when  a pointer is  pointing to member function  it  can only point member functions within the class. But how can i point to a member function outside the class?

for example:

```
class A
{
public:
    int add(int x)
    {
        return x+x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef int (A::*pointer)();
    pointer func = &A::add;
    A objt;
    B objt2;

    obt2.*func(2);// the compiler give me an error of incompatible with object type ‘B’

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Chet : That doesn't solve the fact that calling an `A` member function on an instance of `B` is nonsensical.

Comment: Whatever problem you are trying to solve with this concept is probably solved easier and *better* using another approach.  In C++ methods and functions are one in the same, unlike Smalltalk and other pure OO languages.  Rearrange your solution to use practical features of the language such as inheritance or some design pattern that achieves your end.  If you share your actual goal someone might be able to suggest some valid approaches.

Comment: @ildjarn Oops. missed that lol

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run it as follows:

```
(*func)(&objt, 2)
```

Better choice would be to use boost::bind/boost::function instead:

```
boost::function<int(int)> func = boost::bind(&A::add, &objt, _1);
func(2);
```

I just noticed that you're trying to make it run as if it were a method of class B.
It's completely nonsensical, but if you don't care about correctness and like to live dangerously with completely unpredictable results, it's easier to do this:

```
((A *) &objt2)->add(2);
```

Comment: i did not explained my self clearly sorry. My question is not @Chet ildjarn.
I am implementing a class in omnetpp. This class defines a module in my simulation.I want to access a method using a pointer. This method is implemented in a another class, that defines another MOdule in my simulation.

Comment: If `A` and `B` have no relationship, dereferencing `(A *) &objt2` yields UB.

Answer (score 0):

If `B` uses `A` (calls some `A`'s member) then `B` *depends* on `A` and you can implement this by simply providing `B` with pointer to `A` through which it can call `A`'s methods - see class `B1` below in the code.

You can wrap the call of `A`'s member into a separate object - functor. You can create generic solution by implementing it as a template class and providing address of the object `A`, address of the method and argument. For this, see implementation of class `B2`.

```
class A
{
public:
    int add(int x)
    {
        return x+x;
    }
};

typedef int (A::*MEMFN)(int);

class B1
{
public:
    void InvokeAAdd(A* pA, int x)
    {
        cout << "result = " << pA->add(x) << endl;
    }
};

template<class T, typename TMemFn, typename TArg, typename TRetVal>
class B2
{
    T* pT;
    TMemFn memFn;
    TArg arg;
public:
    B2(T* pT, TMemFn memFn, TArg arg) : 
      pT(pT), memFn(memFn), arg(arg){}

    TRetVal operator()()
    {
        return (pT->*memFn)(arg);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B1 b;
    b.InvokeAAdd(&a, 2);

    B2<A, MEMFN, int, int> b2(&a, &A::add, 2);
    cout << "result (via functor) = " << b2() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
result = 4
result (via functor) = 4
```